# If $X_n = n \ \text{w.p.} \ \frac{1}{n}$ and $X_n = 0 \ \text{w.p.} \ 1-\frac{1}{n}$, what is $E\left[X_n \mathbf{1}_{(|X_n|>t)}\right]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we have a random variable $X_n$ such that

$$X_n=\begin{cases}0, &\text{with probability }1-\frac1n\\n, &\text{with probability }\frac1n\end{cases}$$
How can I find $E\left[X_n \mathbf{1}_{(|X_n|>t)}\right]$?

My intuition is that that only time the expectation is not zero is when $(|X_n|>t)$, which occurs with probability $P(|X_n|>t)$. However, from here I do not know how to calculate the joint probability. I know that the answer should be $1$, but just dont know how to get it.

Does anyone have a hint? thanks.

Comment: for $n>t$, $E(X_n; |X_n|>t)=E(X_n)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_n$ is a discrete random variable which takes only two values $0$ and $n$, you can use directly the formula of the expectation (of the function of a random variable) $$E[g(X_n)]=\sum_{x}g(x)P(X_n=x)$$ with $g(x)=x\cdot \mathbf 1_{(|x|>t)}$ and $x\in \{0,n\}$. The result is then straightforward

\begin{align}E[X_n \mathbf 1_{(|X_n|>t)}]&=0\cdot \mathbf 1_{(|0|>t)}P(X_n=0)+n\cdot \mathbf 1_{(|n|>t)}P(X_n=n)\\[0.2cm]&=0+n\cdot\mathbf1_{(|n|>t)}\cdot \frac1n=\mathbf1_{(|n|>t)}\end{align} which shows that indeed the expectation is equal to $1$ iff $|n|>t$ (as was more or less your intuition).

Comment: One initial blunder I made was that I thought I had to sum through all values of $n = 1, 2, ...$ to infinity. Do you know why that is not the right way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: $X_n$'s are different random variables, so this is not correct. To avoid such mistakes write down $X_1$, $X_2$ to see what happens. For example $P(X_1=1)=1/1=1, P(X_1=0)=1-1=0$. So $E[X_1]=1\cdot 1+0=1$. Then repeat for $X_2$: $P(X_2=2)=1/2, P(X_2=0)=1-1/2=1/2$. So $E[X_2]=1\cdot 1/2+0=1$. If you still do not feel comfortable (or if you want to introduce $t$) then repeat for $X_3$ (or for $X_1, X_2$ for some $t$). After that you will avoid such mistakes. $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ are different random variables, each taking only $2$ values (0 and n) so it is not correct what you did.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_n=X_n \mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|>t)}$

If $n\le t$, $|X_n|\le t$ with prob. 1, hence $Y_n=0$ with prob. 1. In this range, $E[Y_n]= 0$.

If $n > t$, $X_n=n>t$ with prob. $1/n$, hence $Y_n=n$ with prob $1/n$ ($0$ elsewhere). 
In this range, $E[Y_n] =n \times \frac{1}{n} + 0 \times \frac{1}{1-n}=1$

$$
E[X_n \mathbb{1}_{(|X_n|>t)}]=\begin{cases}
0 & (n\le t)\\
1 & (n > t)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks, although I am wondering why I dont need to find the $|X_n|>t$ for all such $n$. Am I fundamentally missing something? thanks!

Comment: "to find the $|X_n|>t$"? I don't get what you mean. $|X_n|>t$ is an event, and its probability is $1/n$ for $n>t$.

Comment: I see, one problem I had was why didn't we have to do the sum over all values of $n$ to infinity. So I guess here I should view $n$ as a fixed number?

Comment: $X_n$ is not really a single random variable, but a set of random variables indexed by the "time" parameter $n$: that is, for each fixed $n$ you have one random variable (I changed my notation $Y \to Y_n$ to better reflect this). The full set $\{X_n\}$ (the sequence of random variables as a whole) is usually called a stochastic process. But here we are only interested in the statistics of each single $X_n$ (for arbitrary $n$)